# How can i correlate responses with request in aggregate mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to enrich response in out sequence with values from requests in iterate-aggregate scenario? I need to respond with xml that will have response as well as businessId of source business object. operation scope property seems to be buggy and often results with values 2, 3, 3 or 3, 3, 3 instead of sent 1, 2, 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save values you need in properties inside in sequence and use those properties in the out sequence.
You can even save the entire request message in a property inside your in sequence, and use it with xpaths in your out sequence :

save :

```
<enrich>
    <source type="envelope" clone="true"/>
    <target type="property" property="INPUT_MESSAGE"/>
</enrich>
```

use it :

```
get-property('INPUT_MESSAGE')/yourNode/text()
```

Comment: if I would have a simple request response then it would work, but i have an iterate-aggregate scenario so there are n calls from in sequence and out sequence gets called n times. I need to correlate response with the request..

Comment: if you set a property inside iterate's sequence, you can find it's value in your out sequence : you can use that to correlate request and response